# How to return multiple arrays from a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have multiple arrays in a function that I want to use in another function. How can I return them to use in another function

```
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){


    array1;
    array2;
    array3;

    return ????

}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

***as an array*** ;)

```
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){
    var array1 = [11,12,13,14,15];
    var array2 = [21,22,23,24,25];
    var array3 = [31,32,33,34,35];

    return [
     array1,
     array2,
     array3
    ];
}
```

*call it like:*

```
 var test =  this.runThisFunctionOnCall();
 var a = test[0][0] // is 11
 var b = test[1][0] // is 21
 var c = test[2][1] // is 32
```

***or an object:***

```
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){
    var array1 = [11,12,13,14,15];
    var array2 = [21,22,23,24,25];
    var array3 = [31,32,33,34,35];

    return {
     array1: array1,
     array2: array2,
     array3: array3
    };
}
```

*call it like:*

```
 var test =  this.runThisFunctionOnCall();
 var a = test.array1[0] // is 11
 var b = test.array2[0] // is 21
 var c = test.array3[1] // is 32
```

Comment: how would I parse it in the other function?

Comment: This answer is , well, a little more accurate than mine ;) +1

Comment: please look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760401/array-problem-cant-get-the-calues

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your arrays into an array and return it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an *array of arrays*. In other words, a multidimensional array. That way, you can reference all arrays outside of the function within that one returned array.

```js
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){
    array1;
    array2;
    array3;

    return [array1, array2, array3];
}
```

Comment: Link does not work

Comment: Updated the code. Although I think Caspar's answer is much more rigorous. Would just look at that!