# Array can't get the values

Tags: javascript

I have the function like this:

```
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){
    var array1 = [[11,12,13,14,15]];
    var array2 = [[21,22,23,24,25],[12]];
    var array3 = [[31,32,33,34,35]];

    return {
     array1: array1[0],
     array2: array2[0],
     array3: array3[0]
    };
}
```

but when I call it from function 2 then no alerts pop up.

```
function2(){
var test =  this.runThisFunctionOnCall();
        alert(test.array1[0]); 
        alert(test.array2[0]); 
}
```

Comment: @slacks: legacy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760058/how-to-return-multiple-arrays/5760096#5760096

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show more code.

The chances are that the `this` in `function2()` isn't the right one, so your code is throwing an exception and never reaching the `alert()` calls.

Given how short `function2()` is that's pretty much the only way it could ever fail to execute the alerts.

EDIT - it's a simple syntax error:

You have:

```
function2() {
}
```

when it should be

```
function function2() {
}
```

Comment: this is all i have..its testing function

Comment: in which case you must remove all of the `this.` references, the code should then work.

Comment: run your code with a debug window open - it would have told you about the syntax error.

Comment: I concur with this answer.  I just put this code into a simple HTML page and got it working with the change above in Chrome.

Maybe paste an entire HTML page and tell us what browser you're running it in.